# Google Sheets - Add seperate columns and show sum on another sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Ok. Here's my problem. I have a sheet that is created by a Google Form. It is formated like this...

[image]

This is part of an INVENTORY CONTROL. This sheet is showing the INCOMING stock. What I want to do is ADD each column (that could go infinately) for example Col B SVHD-01-8OZCUP and display that number on G2 on the sheet below. I also have another sheet that is basically the same showing OUTGOING stock and the sum of its columns would go in H below.

Then I just Subtract H from G in each row to get the Current Inventory. All I need help on is getting the Check-In Totals and Check-Out Totals from the above sheet onto the below sheet. Thanks.

[image]

Comment: If every product is in a separate column then couldn't you use a formula like `SUM(B2:B)` simply? Am I missing something in understanding your question?

Comment: That would require that I would need to do that for SUM(C2:C), SUM(D2:D),...all the way to SUM(DF2:DF). I'm looking for a way to let Sheets do that for me.

Comment: I also have a sheet that is the Master Inventory List. I controls all the product SKUs and descriptions. So for instance in Column D on the lower sheet I have: `=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A1:A,'Master Inventory list'!A1:L,MATCH("ITEM NAME",'Master Inventory list'!A1:1,0),FALSE)))` to show the Item Name. So if I add a new product I don't want to have to go back through this sheet and hand add all the info.

Comment: Please share a link to a copy of your spreadsheet, with permissions set (when creating the link) to "Anyone with the link..." and "Editor." As it stands, the volunteer contributors here would need to manually enter data into their own sheet before they could even begin, which is a large deterrent. What you want done can be done. Help us help you.

Comment: OK. Here's the Link: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1g1DY3qyGgQjWvtgQ4Nl9KRfXhpEedhlNd1kw8llXJx4/edit?usp=sharing

The sheets I want to change are "Current Inventory list" Column G "Check-in total". That data is currently coming from sheet "Check-in Form" and I want to change it to come from sheet "Re-Order". Thanks. I don't have the equlivent "OUTGOING" sheet yet to the Incoming "Re-Order" sheet.

Comment: In your 'Master' sheet, you show 144 SKU items (Rows 2 - 145). But in your 'Re-Order' sheet, you only have 109 SKU items (Columns B - DH). However, in your 'Current inventory' sheet, you do have 109 SKU items. Before going further, please Hide or delete from your linked spreadsheet copy all sheets except those involved in the posted issue.

Comment: The Current inventory list is showing only Supplier "SAMS" the 'Master' Sheet shows ALL suppliers. We have some special order items that come from other suppliers and I will be creating a seperate sheet for those.

Comment: What is currently happening on the "Current" sheet is the SKU is added from the "Check-In" form, so I guess that will also need to come from the "Re-Order" form. And then the subsequent columns check for the SKU in column A and matches it to items in the 'Master' sheet to get all the other info like Category, Sub Category, Item Name, etc.

Comment: I was using Test A and Test B to try to work through some of this.

Comment: Before I or others invest time looking further into this, I see that a contributor ("Broly") has offered a solution below. Please check that and either mark his post as "Best Answer" to signify that the issue is fully resolved or comment on his post as to what, if anything, is not working as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE 2:

Making the `SEQUENCE` part of the formula dynamic as per the discussion in comments:

`=ArrayFormula(IFNA(VLOOKUP("sum "&A2:A, TRANSPOSE(QUERY({'Re-Order'!A1:DF}, "select "&TEXTJOIN(", ", 1, ("sum(Col"&SEQUENCE((COUNTA('Re-Order'!1:1)-1), 1, 2)&")"))&"", 1)), 2, 0)))`

This will only work if you do not have empty columns in the sheet.

UPDATE:

Added this formula in `D2` in your `Test B` sheet:

`=ArrayFormula(IFNA(VLOOKUP("sum "&A2:A, TRANSPOSE(QUERY({'Re-Order'!A1:DF}, "select "&TEXTJOIN(", ", 1, ("sum(Col"&SEQUENCE(109, 1, 2)&")"))&"", 1)), 2, 0)))` and it seems to be working. Let me know if you have any questions.

PREVIOUS ANSWER:

Based on the screenshots that you have shared (I have not looked at the sheet in the comments) one way to do it is to sum all columns individually in the form and then lookup the value against the product in the second sheet (screenshot 2 of your question)

You can use the following formula in `G2` in your the sheet in screenshot 2 of your question:

`=ArrayFormula(VLOOKUP("sum "&A2:A, TRANSPOSE(QUERY({inventory_control_sheet_nameA1:DF}, "select "&TEXTJOIN(", ", 1, ("sum(Col"&SEQUENCE(109, 1, 2)&")"))&"", 1)), 2, 0))`

This assumes that the input has columns through `DF`.

Comment: That works well, the only thing is if I add or remove any products from the list, it requires me to change the SEQUENCE number. That's a small thing, but doable.

Comment: Are you going to have continuous columns in `Re-Order` sheet? If yes, then I could share a variation with `COUNTA` that gets the last column and runs the formula without having to change `SEQUENCE`.

Comment: That would be better if possible.

Comment: Updated the original answer. If this works for you then please [accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). Thanks.

Comment: Like I mentioned in the answer above, there should be no empty columns headers in the `Re-Order` sheet. Currently column `DH` onwards is empty and hence this formula is not working.

Comment: If Row 1 in the `Re-Order` sheet contains empty cells then the formula will not work because the `QUERY` formula needs something to make a column name. That's why I checked it first in the comment before updating the answer.

Comment: So, do you have a suggestion of how to fix this?

Comment: Try not having any empty cells in `Re-Order` sheet row 1.
If you need to add products then add new columns and if you need to remove products then delete those columns.

Comment: So, I went back and made sure I have no empty cells in row 1. It didn't fix it. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: The formula in `C2` in `Test B` sheet should work once you remove the non numeric values from the base data (ex `DH3` in 'Re-Order' sheet)

Comment: Hmmm... ok. So Google Forms automatically adds those non numeric values. I'm not sure what to do.

Comment: IS there anyway to only return the column sums that have matching SKUs (Row 1 in Re-Order) to the 'Master' sheet? In other words, columns that don't have a matching SKU won't return anything.